# error: /somepath/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-s3/dist-cjs/index.js:283 useFipsEndpoint: options.useFipsEndpoint ?? false

Tags: node.js, express, aws-sdk, npm-install

**[I'm getting error on starting my node after doing npm install. Suddenly we started receiving this error. For now i have used existing running project's node_modules to make it working. But this error is making me difficult to add new packages through standard npm install command from package json. I m puttng package json file content below -]**

```
error:
   /somepath/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-s3/dist-cjs/index.js:283
       useFipsEndpoint: options.useFipsEndpoint ?? false,
                                                 ^
   SyntaxError: Unexpected token ?
       at new Script (vm.js:80:7)
       at createScript (vm.js:274:10)
       at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:326:10)
       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:664:28)
       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
       at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
       at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
       at Object.<anonymous> (/somepath/node_modules/s3-files/s3-files.js:2:40)
       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
       at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3),
  level: 'error',
  message:
   'uncaughtException: Unexpected token ?\n/somepath//node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-s3/dist-cjs/index.js:283\n    useFipsEndpoint: options.useFipsEndpoint ?? false,\n                                              ^\n\nSyntaxError: Unexpected token ?\n    at new Script (vm.js:80:7)\n    at createScript (vm.js:274:10)\n    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:326:10)\n    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:664:28)\n    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)\n    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)\n    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)\n    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)\n    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)\n    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)\n    at Object.<anonymous> (/somepath/node_modules/s3-files/s3-files.js:2:40)\n    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)\n    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)\n    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)\n    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)\n    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)',
  stack:
   '/somepath/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-s3/dist-cjs/index.js:283\n    useFipsEndpoint: options.useFipsEndpoint ?? false,\n                                              ^\n\nSyntaxError: Unexpected token ?\n    at new Script (vm.js:80:7)\n    at createScript (vm.js:274:10)\n    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:326:10)\n    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:664:28)\n    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)\n    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)\n    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)\n    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)\n    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)\n    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)\n    at Object.<anonymous> (/somepath/node_modules/s3-files/s3-files.js:2:40)\n    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)\n    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)\n    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)\n    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)\n    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)',`

`{
  "name": "reseller_services",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no testt specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@googleapis/docs": "^0.2.0",
    "akamai-edgeauth": "^0.2.0",
    "app-root-path": "^2.1.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1093.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "body-parser": "~1.0.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.7",
    "ejs": "^2.6.1",
    "elasticsearch": "^15.2.0",
    "email-verify": "^0.2.1",
    "errno": "^0.1.7",
    "exif": "^0.6.0",
    "express": "~4.0.0",
    "express-fileupload": "^1.2.1",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "fastest-validator": "^0.6.19",
    "googleapis": "^74.2.0",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^0.18.0",
    "js-md5": "^0.7.3",
    "kafka-node": "^5.0.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "limiter": "^2.1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "md5": "^2.2.1",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "mongoose": "~4.4",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "multer": "^1.3.0",
    "mysql": "^2.16.0",
    "node-datetime": "^2.1.2",
    "pluralize": "^7.0.0",
    "qrcode": "^1.4.4",
    "request": "^2.88.0",
    "s3-zip": "^3.2.1",
    "shortid": "^2.2.13",
    "tldjs": "^2.3.1",
    "util": "^0.11.0",
    "uuid": "^9.0.1",
    "vcards-js": "^2.10.0",
    "winston": "^3.1.0",
    "xml2js": "^0.4.19",
    "xml2json": "^0.11.2",
    "json2xls": "^0.1.2",
    "busboy": "^0.2.14",
    "got": "^11.8.6",
    "@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg": "^1.1.0",
    "ffmpeg": "0.0.4",
    "fluent-ffmpeg": "^2.1.2",
    "when": "^3.7.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.18.4"
  },
  "description": ""
}
```